# MS SSQL: How to use case when as exec parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, case

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 I'm trying to execute a stored procedure using exec with two parameters. 
The first parameter is an unique identifier. 
The second parameter can either be '2' or '3'.

I'm using a written function which expects the unique identifier and returns true (1) if the case the identifier points to is of type A or false (0) if the case if of type B. 
Similar to VB.Net IIF or the C# equivalent I thought about using Case When to retrieve the value using the mentioned function.

I expected it to look something like this:

```
exec spAddCaseToDeletedInso @Case, (select case when dbo.getCaseOwnerByCaseId(@Case) = 1 then '3' else '2' end)
```

All I get though is a syntax error.

I know that I can work around this issue using the following method:

```
declare @CaseOwner as char(1) = (select case when dbo.getCaseOwnerByCaseId(@Case) = 1 then '3' else '2' end)
exec spAddCaseToDeletedInso @Case, @CaseOwner
```

Is there a way to use Case When to specify a value within the exec line or do I need to use the given workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I expected it to look something like this:
>
> ```
> exec spAddCaseToDeletedInso @Case, (select case when
> dbo.getCaseOwnerByCaseId(@Case) = 1 then '3' else '2' end)
> ```

Your assumption is simply wrong. Check **[`EXECUTE documentation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)**

```
Execute a stored procedure or function
[ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ]
    { 
      [ @return_status = ]
      { module_name [ ;number ] | @module_name_var } 
        [ [ @parameter = ] { value 
                           | @variable [ OUTPUT ] 
                           | [ DEFAULT ] 
                           }
        ]
      [ ,...n ]
      [ WITH RECOMPILE ]
    }
[;]
```

[image]

As you see you can pass as `@parameter`:

- **value**
- **@variable**
- **DEFAULT**

So you need to use variable to hold result of function call and pass it to stored procedure.